# How to reference a Model from within the User model

Tags: django, django-models

The overall use case is that I want to lookup the correct Business for an authenticated User at the start of each view function so that I can look up relevant info for the appropriate Business.

In my app, an User can only be mapped to one Business, and a Business can map to many Users.  To create this mapping, I would like to put a foreign key for a Business in the User model.  The Django documentation I've read states that creating a custom User model, which this would require, is not necessary for most applications.

Having such a mapping of an User to something else seems like a pretty common use case, so I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this that I'm not aware of.

One approach I thought of would be to have a BusinessUserMapping model, which would contain foreign keys to both Businesses and Users.  I could then do a lookup of a BusinessUserMapping where the User foreign key matches the current User, but this seems somewhat convoluted.

Any advice on a better way to look up a Business based on the User?

Comment: You mean like using the user profile instead?

Comment: Why not creating a custom user model by subclassing from `auth.User`?